# How to use 2 different change_list.html for 2 applications in the same django project

Tags: python, django

I have 2 applications in the django project. I want to add different widgets in the change_list.html for the 2 different applications. In settings.py, after adding the change_list.html in the admin directory of the templates in both the applications respectively as,
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ( 
"/home/path/project/application1/templates", 
"/home/path/project/application2/templates",
)

I notice that the change_list.html template considered is from the application1. Only if I comment it, the template from application2 is considered. How to go about? I want both of them to be considered for the 2 different applications. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the section on overriding admin templates: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates (more specifically https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#templates-which-may-be-overridden-per-app-or-model)

Place your `change_list.html` in `admin/application1` in one of the folders parsed by `TEMPLATE_DIRS` or one of the template loaders and that template will be served only for `application1`.

Your current code is always telling django to prioritize matches on the first path over the second.

Comment: I have placed the change_list.html under the 2 diff. applications like this: /home/project/application1/templates/admin/change_list.html /home/project/application2/templates/admin/change_list.html.   In  settings.py I have added :TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

    "/home/project/application1/templates",
    "/home/project/application2/templates",
)
the admin folder is coming after the application/templates/ in which I have placed the 2 different change_list.html. Should the order be changed or ad I missing out something in settings.py? Please guide.

Comment: To show you an exact example: move `/home/project/application1/templates/admin/change_list.html` to `/home/project/application1/templates/admin/application1/change_list.html` and move `/home/project/application2/templates/admin/change_list.html` to  `/home/project/application1/templates/admin/application2/change_list.html`

Comment: Thank you Yuji, I have followed your instructions and it works great now! It requires careful reading especially with the links you mentioned above!

Comment: @user956424, no problem. So now you can see you should probably move the `TEMPLATE_DIRS` setting to point to a more general template directory, and put both `admin/application1/change_list.html` and `admin/application2/change_list.html` in that one directory. Enjoy!